# GNS construction I

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, functional-calculus

> Let $A$ be a $C^*$ algebra, $\phi$ a positive linear functional on $A$. Put a pre-inner product on $A$ by $\langle x,y \rangle _{\phi} = \phi(y^*x)$. Let
>   $$N_\phi := \{x \in A \, : \, \phi(x^*x) = 0 \}$$
>   then $N_\phi$ is a closed left ideal.

How is this so?

---

I think more fundamentally, I am really un familiar with the notion of positive elments of $C^*$ algebras. It would be nice if someone recommends me a reference for the notions behind this proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in N_\phi$, $a\in A$. Then, using that $a^*a\leq \|a\|^2 I$ and that the map $b\longmapsto x^*bx$ preserves positivity, 
$$
\phi((ax)^*ax)=\phi(x^*a^*ax)\leq \|a\|^2\phi(x^*x)=0. 
$$

The basics of positive elements in C$^*$-algebras appear in every book on the topic (like Murphy, Davidson, Kadison-Ringrose, Blackadar, etc.), and others too (like Conway's Functional Analysis).

Comment: Thanks, I will try and understand this proof after I learn more about positivity.

Comment: May be , C*algebra in question don't have a unit, if we should let it be unitization ?

Comment: Yes. Positive linear functionals extend to the unitization, so everything works.